# Typescript: pass value dynamically between classes

Tags: typescript, cucumber

UPDATED:

I have a cucumber test like

```
Given I set some value
Then I print it
```

I have a one class as below

```
export class XXX {

  searchedValue: string;

  @given("I set some value")     
  public async getInfoData(){
    this.searchedValue = await getData.getPlayersId();
  }
}
```

And another class

```
export class YYY {
  const xxx = new XXX();
            
  @then("I print it")
  public async showData(){
    console.log( await xxx.searchedValue)
  }
}
```

but when this `I print it` step is being executed then it gives me `undefined` and value is not passed.
Can someone help, please?

Comment: well you haven't called getInfoData...

Comment: but in XXX i have a property searchedValue so the value shoudn't be set to it?

Comment: Why would it be? You said yourself that it gets the value when you call getInfoData. You haven't done that.

Comment: Where does `getData` in the `XXX` class come from? That code is not included.  Also in your `YYY` class you can't just define a `const` in the class body like that.  It either needs to be moved into a function or made into a property of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
export class XXX {
  searchedValue: Promise<string> = Promise.resolve('');
    
  public async getInfoData() {
    this.searchedValue = getData.getPlayersId();
  }
}
```

And:

```
export class YYY {
  const xxx = new XXX();
        
  public async showData() {
    console.log(await xxx.searchedValue)
  }
}
```

Then:

```
const y = new YYY();
await y.showData(); // will print empty string
y.xxx.getInfoData(); // who ever where ever calls that
await y.showData(); // will print whatever is returned by getPlayersId() when ever available
```

Just remember, that before somebody calls `getInfoData()`, `showData()` will not wait for result. You have to grasp the idea, when/what `Promise` is created and resolved.

But in general, your design not very feasible.